# Twitter Bootstrap tooltip and popover opacity and overlay

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to decide on tooltip or popover .. or use both based on need.
Here is the issue.

I have a bootstrap top stationary navbar on my site. The site is white and the navbar is dark blue.

When using the tooltip it overlays over the navbar and has a slight opacity to it which I really don't care for.
When using the popover it has no opacity but hides behind the top navbar.

So I guess this is a dual question if I want to use both. How do I take off the opacity of the tooltip and make the popover hover over the topbar. Having the option of using both would ideal.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Both of these changes can be solved using a bit of CSS.  I recommend that you do not directly modify the Twitter Bootstrap CSS, but instead link to a different stylesheet.  Make sure to include this new stylesheet after including the Bootstrap stylesheet so that it overrides the Bootstrap CSS.  At the time of writing, the most recent version of Bootstrap is 2.1.1, so all comments are based off of that assumption.

**For Tooltip**

The effect of the tooltip is defined in the .tooltip.in rule on line 5003 as follows:

```
.tooltip.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

To remove the effect, insert in your new stylesheet the following:

```
.tooltip.in {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

**For Popover**

On the web, one object is placed under another due to a lower z-index.  The z-index of popover is defined in line 5080 as follows:

```
.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1010;
  ...
}
```

In this version of Bootstrap, however, the default (static) navbar, does not have an explicit z-index set, so it defaults to 0.  Since that is the case, the popover should already be over the navbar.  If you are using an older version of Bootstrap, you can fix this by finding the z-index of the navbar and setting the z-index of the popover to a higher number.  You can do that by adding the following code to the new stylesheet:

```
.popover {
  z-index: ###;
}
```

Comment: When I include the tooltip modifications it stops working all together, at the main bootstrap css or added css level. Although the popover addition did fix the overlay problem. The popover is pretty cool so I may just go with that one for now.

Comment: should be
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=1);

Comment: Good catch.  I'll fix that.

Comment: Although it should also be filter: alpha(opacity=100); :)

Comment: Should be .tooltip.show

Answer (score 2):

This depends on which version of bootstrap you're using, but the opacity will be set in the *`bootstrap.css`* file. (I'm looking at v2.0.1)

The only opacity setting I can see in the *`bootstrap.css`* file is on line 2963:

```
.tooltip.in {
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
```

Thus, you can change the opacity value to whatever fits better.

As for floating below the navbar, this will be due to it's `z-index` relative to the navbar. The `z-index` of the popover is set on line 2857:

```
.modal-open .popover {
  z-index: 2060;
}
```

So you could change that to a `z-index` higher than is used for the static navbar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried modifying the css file and the tooltip stopped working. Not sure why.

Comment: Have you made sure the syntax is correct? What have you changed? I'm not sure of the version you're using either.

Comment: 2.1.1 of bootstrap. Yeah .. I checked the syntax. I will keep playing with it and see what I can come up with. As long as I have one I will be good for now.

Comment: Ahh. I'm behind on 2.0.1. Glad you've sorted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this CSS to overwrite default setting

```
.tooltip.show {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```