# Bootstrap Tooltip Opacity changes?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, marionette

I've been adding some Twitter Bootstrap tooltips to a basic survey site I've been creating to learn Backbone.

All of my tooltips look correct except the tooltip added to the branching button.

Here's how the bad one looks:
[image]

Here's how all of the others look:
[image]

It's almost like it has an opacity of .8 while the others are 1. But I'm not changing how I'm adding them so I'm perplexed as to what's going on.

I found a different [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020310/twitter-bootstrap-tooltip-and-popover-opacity-and-overlay) that recommends doing:

```
.tooltip.in {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Here's how I'm adding a good tooltip:

```
<div id="arrow-up"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" title="You can rearrange the order that the questions appear in using the arrows next to each question." data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"></i> </div>
```

Another version with the `?`:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="imageQuestion" class="image-question" checked> 
<label for="imageQuestion">Add Image to Question</label> 
<i class="fa fa-question-circle tooltip-info" title="If you would like to add an image to the question, check the 'Add Image to Question' box." data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"></i>
```

Here's how I'm adding the bad one (possibly of note - this view is a child view of the view that contains the other tooltips. The Question view has many Answer childviews):

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%= @id %>" class="btn manage-skip active"><i class="fa fa-code-fork" title="You can branch your survey answers so that certain answers will lead to different questions. Use this to tailor your messages and survey paths to the people that you are looking to find." data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"></i></a>
```

Then in both the Answer and Question views I show the tooltips view this:

```
onShow: ->
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

Comment: May be you can try using your dev tool and inspect to see what is the difference between the two and which css was causing the problem?

Comment: The branch tooltip looks like it's applied to a button that is also somewhat transparent. Does the tooltip exist inside an element that has opacity applied?

Comment: The dev tool doesn't really work - as soon as I hover away the element gets removed. At least I haven't found a good way to use it :(

Comment: DavidG, I think you were kind of right - though I haven't been able to figure out where that button has a different opacity from though. Adding it to the button group seems to work, though isn't quite what I was hoping for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that I was trying to attach a tooltip within a link to a modal. When I added it to a div wrapped around the `a` it worked as expected:

```
<div class="inline" title="You can branch your survey answers so that certain answers will lead to different questions. Use this to tailor your messages and survey paths to the people that you are looking to find." data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<%= @id %>" class="btn manage-skip active"><i class="fa fa-code-fork"></i></a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap 4.0

```
.tooltip.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```