# Bootstrap tooltip HTML with font awesome icons on <i> anchor tag not working on focus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, blazor, font-awesome

I have the following HTML, it is working as expected (when hovering to the "!" symbol, the tooltip appears), however as because one of them have the link inside the tooltip, I would like it to act like "focus" and also "hover" at the same time, thus when I hover the tooltip with link inside it, it still act like "hover" (the tooltip disappear when I am not hovering the HTML, but when I click on the HTML, it will act like "focus" which the tooltip still appears and will disappear when I am click outside of the HTML)

How can I achieve it for "focus" and also "hover"?

Here is the code that I am using:

**HTML Code**

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="This is a tooltip with no HTML"></i>
<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="This is a tooltip with <a href='#'>HTML</a>"></i>
This is a tooltip after HTML
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
);
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
});
```

and also, if I am hovering to the tooltip, I still can see "This is a tooltip after HTML" in the background like the following image, how can I make the tooltip background is solid? So that the text of "This is a tooltip after HTML" not appear when I am hovering the tooltip

**Image**
[image: Text of "This is a tooltip after HTML" still visible when hovering to the tooltip]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to make a Bootstrap icon tooltip work with hover and focus**

To make the icon work, you will need to use a tag that can receive the focus.  One way to do this is to replace the `<i>` tag with a `<span contenteditable>` tag.  The icon will display the same, but it will now work with both hover and focus.  View the code snippet to see it working.

Your second question, if I understood correctly, asks how to hide the tooltip on hover. That can be done by simply setting the trigger attribute to focus only: `data-bs-trigger="focus"`. See the example in the snippet.

**Update**

From comments, the second question asks how to change the tooltip background color opacity.  The default is 0.9, which allows text under the tooltip to remain slightly visible. For Bootstrap versions 4 & 5, the following css sets the background to solid.  For earlier Bootstrap versions, see this  [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13020707/943435).

**Update 2**

The original solution added the `contenteditable` attribute to allow focus on the element. However, a side effect of that is that it also allows the user to enter text. To allow focus, but disable user input, we need to add `event.preventDefault()` to the keypress and paste events. We can also hide the blinking text caret with css as shown:

```
<span contenteditable onkeypress="event.preventDefault()" onpaste="event.preventDefault()" style="caret-color: transparent;" ...etc
```

**Complete working code snippet**

```
<style>
    .tooltip-inner { 
       opacity: 1 !important; 
       filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    }
</style>
```

```js
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
);
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
});
```

```css
.tooltip-inner { 
  opacity: 1 !important; 
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

```html
<h6>Bootstrap Icon Tooltip Example</h6>


<span contenteditableonkeypress="event.preventDefault()" onpaste="event.preventDefault()" style="caret-color: transparent;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation mt-4" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="This is a tooltip with <a href='#'>HTML</a>"></span>
This tooltip uses focus and hover. Hover and then click the icon.

<br/>

<span contenteditable onkeypress="event.preventDefault()" onpaste="event.preventDefault()" style="caret-color: transparent;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation mt-4" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-trigger="focus" title="This is a tooltip with <a href='#'>HTML</a>"></span>
This tooltip uses focus only. You must click the icon to view the tooltip.

<style>
  /* optitonal - removes focus border outline */
  span.fa-solid { outline: none; }
</style>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Bootstrap 4 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
-->

<!-- Bootstap 5 -->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>



<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Hi @Roberto, thank you for your answer, it works as expected. However for the second question, it is not what I want to ask, what I want to achieve is when you hover to the tooltip, I want to make the tooltip background is solid without user can see the text behind the tooltip, right now user still can see text behind the tooltip background when user hover to the tooltip itself (for this case: `This tooltip uses focus and`) (the text is not somewhat visible because of the tooltip background, but you still can see the text). Thanks

Comment: @Reinhardt - Yes, you can fix the background with some css.  My updated answer shows how to make that change.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Yogi, sorry for asking another question, I have tried your answer and now it is working as expected. However, I have a problem which when you focusing into the HTML that has `contenteditable` property, you can enter any characters that you want, which supposed to be not allowed. How can I make it to not be able to enter any characters on the HTML that has `contenteditable` property? Thank you very much

Comment: @Reinhardt - That is a good question and an improvement. See "Update 2" of the answer showing how to make those changes.

Comment: Hi @Yogi, well noted on this, thank you very much :) it works fine now :)