# Bootstrap tooltip HTML on focus able to enter characters

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Referring to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580952/bootstrap-tooltip-html-with-font-awesome-icons-on-i-anchor-tag-not-working-on) which is already answered, I would like to ask another question, when I am focusing into the tooltip which has `contenteditable` property on it, I can enter the text on it which supposed not allowed.

I have tried to put `pointer-events: none`, however I can still enter any characters on the HTML tag that has `contenteditable` property.

How can I solve this?

```js
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
);
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
});
```

```css
span[contenteditable] {
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h6>Bootstrap Icon Tooltip Example</h6>


  <span contenteditable class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation mt-4" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="This is a tooltip with <a href='#'>HTML</a>"></span> This tooltip uses focus and hover. Hover and then
  click the icon.

  <br/>

  <span contenteditable class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation mt-4" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-trigger="focus" title="This is a tooltip with <a href='#'>HTML</a>"></span> This tooltip uses focus only. You must click the icon
  to view the tooltip.
</body>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. You're loading 3 _and_ 5 in your fiddle, which is confusing.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Why do you have the `contenteditable` attribute on the element if you don't want it to be editable? What does this have to do with tooltips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has already been answered from the following [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580952/bootstrap-tooltip-html-with-font-awesome-icons-on-i-anchor-tag-not-working-on?noredirect=1&lq=1) by Yogi with the following proposed answer:

**HTML**

```
<span contenteditable onkeypress="event.preventDefault()" onpaste="event.preventDefault()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-exclamation mt-4" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-trigger="hover focus" title="This is a tooltip with <a href='#'>HTML</a>"></span>
```

or with **jQuery**

```
$("[data-bs-toggle=tooltip]").on("keypress paste", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thank you for all who visited or answered this question